# How to archive out of ram data from redis to mysql

Tags: mysql, redis, archive

We are looking for a way to archive out of ram data from `Redis` to `Mysql`. We are using `Redis` as a front end to `MySql` as we have a high volume of data-writes coming in but need to access all data via `MySql` over the long term.

Our data is based on analytic data which makes it easy to access and delete from `Redis` once it has been moved over to `MySql`.

We are building a front end node based api to abstract access to the data - so if the time range is within the last 10 minutes it would call `Redis` for the data, after that period it will call `MySql`.

What would the best way to move the older data from `Redis` over to `MySql` as it moves through the `redis` cue and falls outside of the 10 min range ? Keeping in mind our `Redis` server will be growing into a cluster itself and will need full redundancy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009297/the-faster-method-to-move-redis-data-to-mysql have a look